# Cant seem to find where to add text in a tab eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

I know how to add text and textviews in eclipse (xml) but what about tabs. I treid adding it but couldnt work so hope someone can help me. If you need any more info please answe this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you given this a swirl?

The android tutorials are pretty self explanatory.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: OK thanks, that shows how to add tabs but what about putting text in the tab as I can't seem to work out how to? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So your main.xml file should have a FragmentTabHost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then inside your Main class where you set the contentView to this xml file inside the onCreate,
You'll apply something like this in a sort:

This sets a new tab to a "Questions" tab, and it calls a new class, here for example it calls Question class.

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Questions").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qtab)), Questions.class, null);
```

In this second class, just have it's setContentView to it's own xml file. And that will be inside the tab.

Check out my svn on google code here for an example.
Main.java has the tab initializer and it's main_layout.xml for the tabhost

and the questions or answers class, with the xml files for those corresponding in the res/layout folder as well.

[Planned ParentHood "SafeText" application](https://code.google.com/p/ppsafetext/source/browse/#svn/trunk/ppsafetext/src/com/example/ppsafetext)

Comment: This look good but i dont understnad it. What are answers and questions and i just want to work out how the user can click a button and it makes another tab for them, plus how to enter text.

Comment: Show me what code you have now. It'll be easier for me to look at it and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[Swipe Tab Layout](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

[Simple Tab Layout](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Comment: cant seem to wo0rk out how to do it? canyou give me a little help.thanks

Comment: everything is explained there in details, check again.